# how to serialize django.conf.settings to json

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error...

Object of type 'Settings' is not JSON serializable

Here is my code

```
from django.conf import settings
import json
def get_settings(request):
    responce = settings.__dict__
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(responce),content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: You might give [JsonPickle](http://jsonpickle.github.io/) a try. It is good at serializing complex objects.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Your settings are internal to your app, and apart from anything else contain the secret key which should *never* be revealed.

Comment: I completely agree, but i want to debug template path or some other setting variables at run time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`django.conf.settings` is not Json serializable, thought you can go throught and create `dict()` then give it to `HttpResponse`. Hope it helps!

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings


def get_settings(request):
    context = {}
    for setting in dir(settings):
        if setting.isupper():
            context[setting] = getattr(settings, setting)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context, indent=4), content_type="application/json")
```